# Copying .bashrc and .profile does not change anything?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I have a root bash profile setup which has autocomplete and all the nice colours, but there is nothing setup for my actual user (non root).

So I decided to copy the files `.bashrc` and `.profile` from `/root` to my home folder: `/home/steve`.

I also changed permission `steve:steve 775`

However my bash is still not setup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: it says `source not found`, when I call as root it returns nothing.

Comment: It seems that you are not using `bash`.  Try `echo $SHELL`; it should produce `bash`.  If not, change your shell.  Try logging in and out or opening a new terminal window for the changes to `~/.bashrc` to take effect.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/sh`...I am not using a desktop environment it is purely terminal

Comment: you are not using bash. in /etc/passwd change /bin/sh to /bin/bash for
user steve

Comment: thank you, that worked. If you want to put as answer and just explain what that `/etc/passwd` is doing it would be appreciated.